# not sure what to put in action attribute in form

Tags: python, html, django

This code is for my signup page as you can see action is set for signup

```
{% block content %}

<form class="form-horizontal" action="signup" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

This is my views.py in the same app

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return redirect('app:home')
            # log the user in
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

This is my url for which doesn't work

```
path('signup/', accounts_views.signup, name='signup')
```

Comment: Is the URL where the form is rendered the same as the URL where the form should be submitted to? You probably just need to remove the action attribute, by default forms will be submitted to the current URL

Comment: no, it supposes to send the user to the home page but it doesn't and I tried removing the action attribute

Comment: What happened when you removed the action attribute?

Comment: Nothing but now I gave up on that project and started another one. I now follow the django docs and encountered another error. It says no module named polls but it does exist